# Should an application server be restarted after making any changes in any class?

Tags: java, deployment, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have 2 EARs deployed on my application server(WAS). Now if I made any changes in class of one project corresponding to EAR one do I need to restart the server? Or do I need to republish just that EAR without affecting others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to restart the server for resources bundled in your applications. See the Infocenter topics for options and procedures: [Updating enterprise application files](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/trun_app_upgrade.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have dynamic class reloading feature enabled for that project in websphere admin console, then you need not to restart the server.